# not printing file contents in parallel

Tags: scala, file-io, fileinputstream

I am trying to print out the contents of the file, yet every time I run this code nothing returns. I know the file exists (because of line 4) and has contents. Why doesnt this code return results?

```
 import scala.xml._
 import collection.mutable.HashMap
 import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}

 val noDupFile="nodup_steam_out.txt"
 println(Files.exists(Paths.get(noDupFile))) //returns true

object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {

    io.Source.fromFile(noDupFile).getLines().toStream.par.foreach((res:String)=>{
        println(res)
    })
```

EDIT: After proposed answers I updated my code to take suggestions:

```
 import scala.xml._
 import collection.mutable.HashMap
 import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}

 val api="BLAH"

object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val noDupFile="nodup_steam_out.txt"
    println(Files.exists(Paths.get(noDupFile))) //returns true
    io.Source.fromFile(noDupFile).getLines().toStream.par.foreach((res:String)=>{
        /*
        val url=("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key="+api+"&steamids="+res+"&format=xml")
        //http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetFriendList/v0001/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamid=76561197960435530&relationship=friend
        //http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamid=76561197960434622&format=json
        //http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetRecentlyPlayedGames/v0001/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamid=76561197960434622&format=json
        //http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerBans/v1/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamids=XXXXXXXX,YYYYY
        val str = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url.toString,"utf-8").mkString
        val x=xml.XML.loadString(str)       
         val allNodes = x \\ "response" \\ "players" \\ "player" flatMap(_.child) filter(!_.isAtom)
        allNodes.foreach(n => {
            print(s"${n.label}: ${n.text},")
        })
        */
        println(res)
    })
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is missing closing braces for the Object HelloWorld.

Also, you need to place your val into the object. If you try to `scalac` your file it should spit an error. Working code:

```
import scala.xml._
import collection.mutable.HashMap
import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}

object HelloWorld {

val noDupFile="nodup_steam_out.txt"
println(Files.exists(Paths.get(noDupFile))) //returns true
    def main(args: Array[String]) {

    io.Source.fromFile(noDupFile).getLines().toStream.par.foreach((res:String)=>{
        println(res)
    })  
}}
```

Correct version of the edit code:

```
import scala.xml._
 import collection.mutable.HashMap
 import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}

    object HelloWorld {
        def main(args: Array[String]) {
            val api="BLAH"
            val noDupFile="nodup_steam_out.txt"
            println(Files.exists(Paths.get(noDupFile))) //returns true
            io.Source.fromFile(noDupFile).getLines().toStream.par.foreach((res:String)=>{
                println(res)
            })
    }}
```

Comment: I just updated my post to include my entire code. I had the closing parens but failed to include them in my original example

Comment: Your  "val api="BLAH"" must go inside the Object. it's out of scope otherwise.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, why didnt scala throw any errors though?